# Laravel Eloquent query with condition and using sum and groupBy

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sum

Let's say we have a website like Amazon, where users are also sellers. We have three models: User, Product, and Order.

Products have a user_id that represent the seller, Orders have a user_id that represent the buyer.

Each order is for one single product.

The following function will get me all of the orders, except the ones where a user purchased a product that they were selling. Then the orders are grouped by year and month.

```
$orders_per_month = Order::whereHas('product',function($q) {
  $q->whereRaw('products.user_id != orders.user_id');
})->get()->groupBy(function($v) {
  return Carbon::parse($v->created_at)->format('Ym');
});
```

But instead of a list of these orders for each year and month, I need the sum of the the "amount" property of these orders for each year and month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a map to iterate each group and get the sum.

```
$orders_per_month = Order::whereHas('product',function($q) {
  $q->whereRaw('products.user_id != orders.user_id');
})->get()->groupBy(function($v) {
  return Carbon::parse($v->created_at)->format('Ym');
})->map(function ($group, $key) {
    return [$key => $group->sum('amount')];
});
```